# java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: I am getting this error?

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to get some data using retrofit but while executing code I am getting this error

```
Exception from call site #4 bootstrap method ,when initializing Retrofit
```

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Your question is okay, but you could add some code, to help the community help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding :

```
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

in your grade file.
Hope this helps in solving your problem